# Converting number of days(int) into days,months and years in java (including leap year)

Tags: java, calendar

1. I used this code to convert number of days into respecting days,months and year
2. But the result are not precise because i don't take account for leap year and month    with 31 days
3. What is the best way to solve/encounter this issue
4. field_Date1 and field_Date2 are input from my program
5. duration=field_Date2-field_Date1
6. duration is the number of days(int b)
7. In the if else i do the conversion(but the condition are not precise)

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import java.math.RoundingMode;
   import java.text.DecimalFormat;

   if (field_Date1 == null || field_Date2 == null){
       return "";
   } else {
       Date startDate = (Date)field_Date1;
       Date endDate = (Date)field_Date2;
       long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
       long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);
       long diff = duration - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(diffInDays);
       double diffToHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
       float hoursToDay = (float) (diffToHours / 24.0);
       float a =hoursToDay+diffInDays;
       a=Math.floor(a)
       int b = (int)a

       if(b<30)
       {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Day: ")
           sb.append(b)
           String c = sb.toString()
           c
       }

       else if(b<366)
       {
           int months = b/30
           int days_out=b%30

           StringBuilder p1 = new StringBuilder("Days: ")
           StringBuilder p2 = new StringBuilder("Months: ")
           StringBuilder p3 = new StringBuilder("     ")


           p1.append(days_out)
           p2.append(months)
           p2.append(p3)
           p2.append(p1)

           String c=p2.toString()
           c
       }

       else
       {
           StringBuilder p1 = new StringBuilder("Months: ")
           StringBuilder p2 = new StringBuilder("Years: ")
           StringBuilder p3 = new StringBuilder("     ")
           StringBuilder p4 = new StringBuilder("Days: ")

           int years = b/365
           int days_out=b%365

           if(days_out>30)
           {
               int m1 = days_out/30
               int m2 = days_out%30

               p2.append(years)
               p1.append(m1)
               p4.append(m2)
               p2.append(p3)
               p2.append(p1)
               p2.append(p3)
               p2.append(p4)

               String hj = p2.toString()
               return hj
           }

           else
           {
           p4.append(days_out)
           p2.append(years)
           p2.append(p3)
           p2.append(p4)

           String c=p2.toString()
           return c
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you able to use java.time from Java 8 or Joda Time? Both of those would make it much cleaner...

Comment: @JonSkeet What function in java.time can be used? i see the method description in tutorialspoint, but the method are more to comparison that most-likely cant solve my issue sir

Comment: Well if you can confirm that you can use Java 8, I'll write it up as an answer... but it would also be useful if you'd give concrete examples, and also say what form your input data is in. (`java.util.Date` isn't a great starting point.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've do some research on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html. Sir, can you give me any tips/ what function to be used because i would like try it own my own first. Any rough idea also would be nice to shared. Thanks in advance.*(I've read your blog post on Stack Overflow-related emails first)

Comment: DS Stack has now given answers for both Joda Time and Java 8. Basically, the Period type is your friend in both cases...

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

Try using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5:

Snippet will look something like this:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

Date startDate = (Date)field_Date1;
Date endDate = (Date)field_Date2;
int days = Days.daysBetween( new DateTime(startDate), new DateTime(endDate) ).getDays();
```

## java.time

Or the following method from java.time (Java8) can be used:

```
public static Period between(LocalDate startDateInclusive,
                             LocalDate endDateExclusive)
```

This obtains a period between two dates, consisting of the number of years, months, and days.

Comment: I suggest also passing a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) to the constructor of [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

Comment: @DS Stack Can u provide more brief example(java.time) that i can apply into my matter

Comment: `LocalDate startDate = (LocalDate)field_Date1;
LocalDate endDate = (LocalDate)field_Date2;
Period p = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
System.out.println("Duration between the dates is:" + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() +
                   " months, and " + p.getDays() +
                   " days.";`

Comment: @DSStack It was really helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want the difference between two dates in days, including taking into account leap years etc, the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (new in Java 8) gives you:

```
LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.DECEMBER, 1);
LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.MARCH, 12);
long days = firstDate.until(secondDate,ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

gives you 467 days.

Alternatively,

```
Period period = firstDate.until(secondDate);
```

will give you a Period object, which stores the time broken down into years, months and days ie. instead of 467 days, you get 1 year, 3 months and 11 days. This is good for human readability. However, if you want the total days, it's not easy to get that from the Period object, so you're better off going with the first option I gave.